# Argo helm chart does not apply my custom values.yml file

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I deploy Argo with Helm 3 to my cluster

```
helm upgrade --install argo argo/argo-cd -n argocd -f argovalues.yaml
```

My `argovalues.yml` file is the following

```
global.image.tag: "v2.0.1"
server.service.type: "NodePort"
server.name: "kabamaru"
server.ingress.enabled: true
server.metrics.enabled: true
server.additionalApplications: |
  - name: guestbook
    namespace: argocd
    additionalLabels: {}
    additionalAnnotations: {}
    project: default
    source:
      repoURL: https://github.com/argoproj/argocd-example-apps.git
      targetRevision: HEAD
      path: guestbook
      directory:
        recurse: true
   destination:
      server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
      namespace: argocd
   syncPolicy:
     automated:
       prune: false
       selfHeal: false
```

and .... none of these values is applied.It is very frustrating.

If I do the following

```
helm upgrade --install argo argo/argo-cd -n argocd --set server.name=hello
```

it works and changes successfully!
What on earth is going on?

Comment: Did you try to use the whole name flag `--values` instead just `-f`?

Comment: Tbh no .... I'll give it a try!

Comment: No, nothing happens. No error, but no change either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using helm chart upgrade command with the option **--set-file** and it's working correctly :

```sh
helm upgrade --install argo argo/argo-cd -n argocd --set-file argovalues.yaml
```

there are  other option like **--set** and **--set-string** like that:
[image]
I think that can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: Error: failed parsing --set-file data: key map "argovalues" has no value

Answer (score 0):

**The solution**

I managed to make it work like this:

`argovalues.yaml`

```
server:

  service:
    type: "NodePort" #by default 80:30080/TCP,443:30443/TCP

  image:
    tag: "v2.0.1"

  autoscaling:
    enabled: true

  ingress:
    enabled: true

  metrics:
    enabled: true

  additionalApplications:
   - name: bootstrap
     namespace: argocd
     additionalLabels: {}
     additionalAnnotations: {}
     project: default
     source:
       repoURL: https://github.com/YOUR_REPO/argotest.git
       targetRevision: HEAD
       path: bootstrap
       directory:
         recurse: true
     destination:
       server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
       namespace: argocd
     syncPolicy:
      automated:
        prune: true
        selfHeal: false
```

Note: the wrong indentation can drive you crazy!